# What's the easiest way to acquire a lock on a shared variable for a UNIX C program?

Tags: c, unix, locking

I am writing a C UNIX program that is threaded and shares one variable across all threads. What would be the easiest way to acquire a lock on this variable? I can't find any small libraries just for locking in UNIX.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [pthread_mutex_lock](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html), if you're already using pthreads.

Quick example, where `counter` is the shared variable and `mutex` is a mutex variable of type `pthread_mutex_t`:

```
/* Function C */
void functionC()
{
   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
   counter++;
   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot lock a variable.  The subject of intensive research, STM is a promising candidate but nobody has yet written an operating system that uses it.

No, you can only block code that tries to access that variable.  Which is typically done with a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

There are a *wide* variety of ways to do this, and I encourage you to explore them all, but a good starting point is the [mutex implementation in pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes), which has several things going for it: pthreads is available on a lot of platforms and it's [well-designed](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/04/05/pthreads-as-a-case-study-of-good-api-design/).